# Xdebug and a few remote_hosts

Tags: xdebug

I've got an apache server and I configured on it `Xdebug`.
I set as `xdebug.remote_host` my IP address so it looks like:

```
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.101
```

But I would like other computers also would be able to use `Xdebug` - how to set a few IP addresses from LAN ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an article about [multi user debugging](http://derickrethans.nl/debugging-with-multiple-users.html)

Comment: I took it from the XDebug Documentation *gg*